# Function does not return expected instance

Tags: python

I have a very specific problem in my code and I just can't figure it out why.
select_desire_tool() returns None.

It seems that when it arrives at return self._associated_instance(value), somehow it finishes some process in the else statement of the for loop and the supposed returned instance is lost.

why is that?

### Return specific instance

```
def _associated_instance(self, argument):
    if RegionConstants.SETTINGS == argument:
        return Settings()
    else:
        test.fail("No such instance found.")
        raise

## Clicks on desired map tools option
# @param[in] self The self object pointer.
# @param[in] value Map tools option to be selected
# @return specific class instance class instance
def select_desire_tool(self, value):
    items_from_list = self.items
    for item in items_from_list:
        if item.name == value:
            while True:
                try:
                    item.click_button()
                    return self._associated_instance(value)
                except LookupError:
                    Base().Scrollbar().scroll_down()
    else:
        if not Base().Scrollbar().at_y_end:
            Base().Scrollbar().scroll_down()
            self.select_desire_tool(value)
        else:
            test.fail("Option was not found in map tools")
            raise
```

Comment: Is the `else` for the `for` loop or the `if` statement? `for: else:` or `if: else:` ?

Comment: We need details of the function call, but the function you have here certainly won't reach that `return` statement for all possible input parameters - and if it doesn't, then it will implicitly return `None`

Comment: You should add logging or debug printing. Code looks complicated for it purpose. Again, `else` statement of `for` loop looks like a mistype. And even if not, it's unnecessary as there is no `break` in the loop. Another possible mistake is that when you call recursively `self.select_desire_tool(value)` you don't return what it returns, i.e. it should be `return self.select_desire_tool(value)`.

Comment: You need to fix the if : else indentation.